# Rails Project on EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have successfully deployed rails project on EC2.

Here are the steps:

1. Clone rails project from github
2. Set up database and database.yml
3. Run `rake db:migrate`
4. Run `rake assets: precompile`
5. Start rails server in production mode

The functionality seems fine. I can see all the HTML. I can see table data. I can add, remove and modify entries. But there is an issue. Images and CSS is gone. Can't figure out what's wrong. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I doubt that this is anyhow related to EC2

Comment: Agreed; this is more likely because you've been running it in development mode until now, and when deploying to production mode your assets are being precompiled and now don't render the same. Try starting Rails in production mode on your box, and see if you still get the issues - if so, it's not EC2.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. You are right. It was a Rails issue. I had to set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production.rb